# How the browser uses the dns configured on the computer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, dns, microsoft-edge

I found an interesting phenomenon.
The following is my environment:
In my LAN, I configured a website: 192.168.27.10, and used dnsmasq to configure a domain name myiste.com for it. As it happens, there is also a website on the public Internet called mysite.com.
I have configured two dns on my local computer, one is my dnsmasq and the other is 8.8.8.8
Before I visited mysite.com, I used cmd's nslookup command to parse it and got the internal network address 192.168.27.10, but when I used the browser, the browser opened mysite.com located on the public network.
This means that when the browser visits, it uses 8.8.8.8 to resolve to get the ip instead of 192.168.27.10 which is resolved by the internal LAN. I tried to clear the dns cache and replace the chrome, edeg, and firefox browsers, and all encountered the same phenomenon. How does the browser choose the dns configured on the computer and why it uses different dns and cmd